# How to concatenate comment + bash alias command call?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, ip

I'm trying to print out my ip address along with a comment in front of it. I have no idea how to do it all in one single line.

```
6 alias showip="ifconfig | grep 'inet' | sed -n '5p' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2"
11 ip=showip
12 ip="ip: $ip"
13 echo ip
```

The output I'm looking for is something along the lines of:

```
ip: 192.168.1.2
```

Thanks a bunch guys.

```
printf 'ip: %s\n' $(showip)
```

UPDATED: PROBLEM SOLVED

Comment: @kmkaplan I'm trying to make a comment before the alias call but display them out in one line....The alias call is showip and prints out the ip. But I don't know how to add a comment before the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question but you may be looking for:

```
printf 'ip: %s\n' $(ifconfig | grep 'inet' | sed -n '5p' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2)
```

Comment: Beautiful!!! Ahh. I see. Thanks dude! I subbed in your printf with my alias instead. Thanks for the help!